# Finding the size of a JFrame Header and Border in different graphics environments

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to render BufferedImages of specific pre-defined sizes on a JPanel contained within a JFrame. I can strictly define the size of the JPanel, but it seems that setting the size of a JFrame sets the total outside area, including the header and borders, and these appear to have different values in different graphical environments. Setting a size which is too large leaves whitespace between the outer edges of the JPanel and the inner edges of the JFrame, and setting a size which is too small causes the image not to be rendered at all.

Is there a way to determine at runtime how much extra space to pad the JFrame size with to ensure neither of these things happen? Or is there a way to size a JFrame based on its inner borders rather than its outer borders?

When the JPanel is the size of the display and the JFrame's extendedState is set to JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH and undecorated is set to true, there is no problem, but I would also like to support a windowed display mode which is consistent throughout different graphical environments, which is where I am encountering this problem.

I initially tried to use constants to pad the size of the JFrame on the computer I was testing the code on, which worked well until I attempted to use it on a different machine. Running the same code on a different computer with a different monitor (albeit the same resolution) led to the extra whitespace between borders, so it seems that constants are not the answer.

It would be useful to know how Swing determines the sizes of these areas, but so far I haven't come across any explanation of this.

Comment: *but it seems that setting the size of a JFrame* - you should NOT be attempting to set the size of a frame. When you do custom painting on a JPanel you override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel. Then you add the panel to the frame and invoke the frame.pack() method. The pack() method will take into account the size of the border, titlebar etc for the current LAF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the JPanel's `getPreferredSize()` to match the size of the image that it holds, add it to the JFrame, and then call `pack()` on the JFrame after all components are added. Let Java size it all correctly for you.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    public static final String IMG_URL_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/"
            + "wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/" 
            + "WomanFactory1940s.jpg/773px-WomanFactory1940s.jpg";
    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImagePanel(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // if the image isn't null, draw it in the JPanel
        if (image != null) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        // if either the image is null or the panel's preferred size
        // has been set, then must use the super's value
        if (isPreferredSizeSet() || image == null) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        } else {
            // otherwise use the image's size for the panel's pref'd size
            int width = image.getWidth();
            int height = image.getHeight();
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui(BufferedImage img) {
        ImagePanel mainPanel = new ImagePanel(img);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image Panel Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // first add all components to the JFrame
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);

        // pack the JFrame to allow it to size all its components and itself
        frame.pack();

        // call this *after* packing only if you want the size fixed
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // then display it
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL imageUrl = new URL(IMG_URL_PATH);
            final BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui(img));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Option two (as camickr points out) is to simply display the image as an ImageIcon within a JLabel, which is a component that sets its preferred size automatically to the size of the icon that it holds. This is useful if you're not going to be using the image as a background for animation or don't wish to have a resizeable image. For example:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageDisplay {
    public static final String IMG_URL_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/"
            + "wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/" 
            + "WomanFactory1940s.jpg/773px-WomanFactory1940s.jpg";

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        BufferedImage img = null;

        try {
            URL imageUrl = new URL(IMG_URL_PATH);
            img = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image Display");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: `I am trying to render BufferedImages of specific pre-defined sizes` - the easiest approach is to just use the BUfferedImage to create an ImageIcon which you add to a JLabel and then you add the JLabel to the frame so there is no need for any custom painting. The JLabel will calculated its preferred size based on the size of the BufferedImage.

Comment: @camickr: yes, you are correct of course. I'm in the habit of drawing within `paintComponent`, since I often add sprite images on top of background images and such

Comment: @camickr: answer edited to include both options/examples

Comment: Thanks, .pack() is indeed the solution I was looking for.